# failed to solve (exit code: 100). Ошибка в Docker

Tags: python, windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Первый раз имею дело с Docker, и не совсем понимаю что происходит. Когда я ввожу следующую команду в терминал:

```sh
docker-compose --env-file config\config.env up --build
```

То спустя нескольких процессов (занимает где то 4 минуты). Терминал выдает следующую ошибку:

> failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python-dev build-essential python3-venv ffmpeg]: exit code: 100

Я использую Windows 11, и так следующим образом выглядит мой `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=random
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on
ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python-dev build-essential python3-venv ffmpeg

RUN mkdir -p /code
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update linux-headers

CMD ["bash"]
```

Хочу отметить что до этого контейнер запускался, но процесс постоянно перезагружался,
из за чего я переустановил Docker, и начал получать подобные ошибки, раньше она тоже была,
но пропала после перезагрузки ПК, и вот она появляется снова после переустановки Docker и не пропадает.

Я буду вам очень благодарен если вы разгадаете это, потому что я убил уже больше месяца чтобы понять в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает при попытке установить пакеты в контейнер.  По идее нужно закоментировать эту строку в dockerfile и запустить контейнер. Затем зайти в контейнер по ssh и попробовать ввести команду вручную. И посмотреть что происходит. Возможно это даст какую-то дополнительную информацию.

Как вариант, такую ошибку может вызывать то что в контейнере не хватает места "на диске" для установки всех пакетов.